# Bash - View a specific line in a file with corresponding line number

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am able to view all line in a file e.g. "address.addr_book" with;

```
awk '{printf "%d\t%s\n", NR, $0}' < address.addr_book
```

This echos all line with line numbers.

e.g.

```
1      John ; 23 ; Male                             
2      Mary ; 42 ; Female
```

However I wish to only view John per say.

I can view "John" without line numbers.

```
grep -i John address.addr_book
```

I was wondering how it would be possible to view him or any specific record including line number.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `grep -n` to print the line number:

```
grep -i -n John file
```

or awk to do the similar thing:

```
awk '/John/{print NR, $0}' file
```

Note this will match any pattern that has John in it, you need to modify your pattern accordingly.

Comment: The top one was exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk '$1=="John" {printf "%d\t%s\n", NR, $0}' < address.addr_book
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
< address.addr_book nl -ba | awk /John/
```